# Why is Ubuntu trying to open my Mono app with Wine instead of Mono?

Tags: linux, file-association, mono-framework

So, I have compiled a C# program on Linux using MonoDevelop. When I try to execute the resulting binary, my system tries and fails to run it as a windows executable, with wine. Wine gives me the following message:

```
$ ~/bin/MyMonoApp
wine: Install the Windows version of Mono to run .NET executables
~/bin/MyMonoApp: command not found
```

I can only convince it to run by explicitly calling `mono`:

```
$ mono ~/bin/MyMonoApp
```

So, how can I make this the default, so I don't have to explicitly call mono every time?

Comment: Type: file MyMonoApp and tell us the results.

Comment: My laptop's cooling fan just died, so I can't work on fixing this until the new one arrives.

Comment: MyMonoApp: PE32 executable for MS Windows (console) Intel 80386 32-bit Mono/.Net assembly

Answer (score 8):

Execution of binaries in the Linux kernel is controlled via the **`binfmt_misc` module** (short for “miscellaneous binary formats”). The way it works is that the kernel looks at the first few bytes of the file and sees if there is a “**magic number**” that characterizes a known file format. The idea is that if the kernel sees the magic number of a .NET executable, it calls `mono`; if it sees the magic number of a jar (Java virtual machine binary), it calls a JRE; etc.

The problem with Mono and Wine is that the magic number is the same — a .NET executable is a Windows executable. If both formats are registered with `binfmt_misc`, whichever is registered last wins. Oops.

On a Debian-derived system, the magic number for Windows executables doesn't invoke wine or mono directly: it goes via a script that performs additional tests to decide which environment to use. The script in question was initially written for Debian; it could be used by other distributions (for instance Ubuntu has kept it).

Apparently your distribution (which one? you don't say!) doesn't use it. The first thing to check would be if some updates you haven't applied includes something similar. If you'd like to port the mechanism, here's where to find the bits; it's a small programming task. The script is `/usr/share/binfmt-support/run-detectors` in the [binfmt-support](http://packages.debian.org/sid/binfmt-support) package (you need the libraries in `/usr/share/perl5/Binfmt` as well); for mono, the detector is `/usr/lib/cli/binfmt-detector-cli` in the [mono-common](http://packages.debian.org/lenny/mono-common) or [mono-runtime](http://packages.debian.org/sid/mono-runtime) package.

If your distribution has no special support, and you don't care about wine binaries, a more manual route would be easier. The `binfmt_misc` module is controlled via the `/proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc` directory. You can **register** a format by writing to `/proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/register`; each file in this directory other than `register` and `status` represents a registered format. Be careful when writing to `register`: if you accidentally register a magic number that matches Linux native executables (ELF), you're likely to hose your system with no remedy other than rebooting. To **unregister** the `wine` format, echo `-1` to `/proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/wine`. The `binfmt_misc` module is documented in `Documentation/binfmt_misc.txt.gz` in the Linux kernel documentation.

One solution to your problem would be to unregister the wine format; you'd have to do that after whichever boot script registers binary formats. An alternative solution is to figure out where in the boot process the wine format is registered and skip this part. A third solution is to find a way to distinguish .NET executables from other Windows executable and register the .NET magic number after the generic Windows magic number.

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu Lucid. I guess the debian script hasn't made it in yet. Could I just download the debian binfmt-support package and build it on ubuntu?

Comment: @Ryan: Ubuntu lucid includes the same support, so something else is wrong. Do `/proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/cli` and `/proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/wine` both show `interpreter /usr/share/binfmt-support/run-detectors`? If you run `/usr/lib/cli/binfmt-detector-cli ~/bin/MyMonoApp; echo $?`, does it show `0` or `1` (`0` means that your executable has been identified as mono)?

Comment: It shows zero. But it still wants to run it with wine.

Comment: Hmm. There is no `/proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/cli`. and `/proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/cli` shows `interpreter /usr/bin/wine`.

Comment: @Ryan: `/proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/cli` should exist if `/usr/bin/mono` does, they're provided by the same package. Does `/var/lib/binfmts/cli` exist? Is the `mono` command `/usr/bin/mono` from the `mono-runtime` package? On the wine side, did you mean `…/wine` shows `interpreter /usr/bin/wine`? Is that wine from Ubuntu universe or from another source?

Comment: There is no `/var/lib/binfmts/cli`, but there is `/usr/share/binfmts/cli`.

Comment: Strange. Look if `cli` has been disabled somehow (but I think that would only happen if you do it explicitly) by running `/usr/sbin/update-binfmts --display`. If it is, you can reenable it with `sudo update-binfmts --enable cli`.